# Selenium throws ElementNotInteractableException for element with role='button'

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to find and click to OK button.
[image]

But selenium says the button is not interactable. I tried almost all ways
`browser.FindElementByCssSelector("div[role='button'][data-id='EBS5u']").Click();`

`browser.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"yDmH0d\"]/div[8]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]").Click();//xpath to this button`

Both these ways don't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is that button located in UI  ?

Comment: @cruisepandey http://wallmaker.ru/epic/view/p3bdu2HKzOb11WTt2bCWCbCm here's screenshot

Comment: Please share the URL

Comment: @cruisepandey oh this is https://takeout.google.com/
You have to check Chrome and then open window where you choose types of chrome data

Comment: I could not find the prompt at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will work in C# but this helped me when I got the same error when using selenium in python.

If the button is not interactable it may be covered by another element on the screen IE a cookie pop up.
This error could also happen if you are trying to click it before the page has loaded.

To get around the popup you could use the "execute_script" function which looks like this in python

```
browser.execute_script("document.querySelector('ENTER CSS SELECTOR HERE').click()")
```

Example:

```
browser.execute_script("document.querySelector('#main > div > div.Root__top-container > div.Root__now-playing-bar > footer > div > div.mF7iSITxB6KQzvdXe4qJ > div > div.player-controls__buttons > div.player-controls__right > button.vwGw2RO2v__qDU_9c5PE').click()")
```

If that doesn't work you could make the driver wait and load the page until the element has loaded properly.

```
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
```

This will make the driver wait until its ready or throw an error after 10 seconds.

Comment: Thank you! Work well, finally. `browser.ExecuteScript("document.querySelector(\"div[role='button'][data-id='EBS5u']\").click()");`

Comment: Selenium intended to imitate real user actions via the GUI. There are 2 elements located by `div[role='button'][data-id='EBS5u']` CSS selector while the first is hidden and not clickable with GUI and the second is visible and clickable normally. Using JavaScript executor to force click on the first element is not the correct approach even if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 buttons located by `div[role='button'][data-id='EBS5u']` CSS selector.
You need to define it with unique sequence.
Like this XPath:

```
(//div[@role='button' and @data-id='EBS5u'])[last()]
```

So your command can be

```
browser.FindElementByXpath("(//div[@role='button' and @data-id='EBS5u'])[last()]").Click();
```

Comment: And thanks to you too, checked this method too, it works well too